# How to use Fedex shipping module

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

I've developed a on demand product building shop where user can create product by selecting their desired type of glass.

Task is: I need to show the shipping charges via Fedex price and product dimensions are with me, Shipping calculated will also applied the checkout.

I'm exploring the : Fedex.php located at app\code\core\Mage\Usa\Model\Shipping\Carrier

Anybody has idea that could save time...very appreciated in advance.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to override the Fedex.php (there are no events you can key into) and then create a new method which does the packing based on the items in the cart. Dimensional Shipping is a complex thing, so obviously you will need to think about your approach there.

If you have access to the FedEx API then you can see where to insert the dimensions in the FedEx request.  You also need to consider when there are multiple packages.

Comment: My credentials correct, i have two store in single magento, store 1 display Fedex shipping cost, but store 2 not displaying shipping cost, how can i solve this issue?